# Why in my flex lexer line count is incremented in one case and is not incremented in the other?

Tags: regex, flex-lexer

My assignment (it is not graded and I get nothing from solving it) is to write a lexer/scanner/tokenizer (however you want to call it). flex is used for this class. The lexer is written for Class Object Oriented Language or COOL.

In this language multi-line comments start and end like this:

```
(* line 1
line 2
line 3 *)
```

These comments can be nested. In other words the following is valid:

```
(* comment1 start (* comment 2 start (* comment 3 *) comemnt 2 end *) comment 1 end *)
```

Strings in this language are regular quoted strings, just like in C. Here is an example:

```
"This is a string"
"This is another string"
```

There is also an extra rule saying that there cannot be an EOF in the comment or in the string. For example the following is invalid:

```
(* comment <EOF>
"My string <EOF>
```

I wrote a lexer to handle it. It keeps track for a line count by looking for a `\n`.

Here is the problem that I'm having:

When lexer encounters an EOF in the comment it increments the line count by 1, however when it encounters an EOF in the string it doesn't do it.

For example when lexer encounters the following code

```
Line 1: (* this is a comment <EOF>
```

the following error is displayed:

> `#2 ERROR "EOF in comment"

However when it encounters this code:

```
Line 1: "This is a string <EOF>
```

the following error is displayed:

> `#1 ERROR "String contains EOF character"

I can't understand why this (line number is incremented in one case and is not incremented in the other) is happening. Below are some of the rules that I used to match comments and string. If you need more then just ask, I will post them.

```
    <BLOCK_COMMENT>{
  [^\n*)(]+ ; /* Eat the comment in chunks */
  ")" ; /* Eat a lonely right paren */
  "(" ; /* Eat a lonely left paren */
  "*" ; /* Eat a lonely star */
  \n curr_lineno++; /* increment the line count */
}

  /*
       Can't have EOF in the middle of a block comment
     */
<BLOCK_COMMENT><<EOF>>  {
    cool_yylval.error_msg = "EOF in comment";
  /*
     Need to return to INITIAL, otherwise the program will be stuck
     in the infinite loop. This was determined experimentally.
   */
  BEGIN(INITIAL);
  return ERROR;
}

  /* Match <back slash>\n or \n */
<STRING>\\\n|\n {
  curr_lineno++;
}
<STRING><<EOF>> {
    /* String may not have an EOF character */
  cool_yylval.error_msg = "String contains EOF character";

  /*
     Need to return to INITIAL, otherwise the program will be stuck
     in the infinite loop. This was determined experimentally.
   */
  BEGIN(INITIAL);
  return ERROR;
}
```

So the question is

Why in the case of a comment the line number is incremented and in the case of a string it stays the same?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You'll still want to link to the class and its materials so we can see what you are supposed to understand.

Comment: You have to login to the Stanford free online classes website and search for a class on compilers. Here is the link, https://lagunita.stanford.edu/courses

Comment: I know this is old, but I think it might be a result of the fact that you have this line: `\n curr_lineno++; /* increment the line count */` in addition to `<STRING>\\\n|\n {
  curr_lineno++;
}`

Comment: @flashburn if you post all of your code, other people can try to duplicate it.  As it stands, any answer would have to include a lot of guesswork.

Comment: @Laurel No it isn't. The first of those is in a `<BLOCK_COMMENT>` condition.

Comment: @flashburn Your question is incomplete without all the rules involving `<STRING>`. Why are you treating backslash followed by `n` as a newline? It isn't.

Answer (score -1):

Because the pattern for a comment doesn't require a newline to exist in order to increment the line number, and the pattern for a string does.

Comment: Eh? They both do.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne: I don't know how you're reading `[^\n*)(]+`, but however it is, it's wrong.